# Regex validation for Singapore names

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to do a regex to validate common Singapore names on Android.

My current regex is `^[A-Za-z\s]{1,}[\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\s]{0,}$`

It can accept any value that has spaces in between, but accept too many other values which make it inapplicable.

The regex should **accept**:

```
Benedict Tan
James Watson
Richard Lim Jun Qi
Tan Ho Wen
Eng Pin Wee
```

The regex should **reject**:

```
Ngee Ann Polytechnic
Institute of Singapore
Singapore University of Technology and Design
ST Electronics
Green View Secondary School
Anderson Primary School
NUS
Ministry of Education
Singapore Press Holdings Pte Ltd
```

This is a tricky one and I cannot figure out how to differentiate them.

-------------------------------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------

One suggestion is to make a list of non-name words like "Institute, School, University, Technology, Design, Company", and reject these.

How can form a regex based on this? 
I am currently trying it out on regex tester and still working on it.

Comment: Short of building a dictionary of disallowed words there is no solution to this problem. Even with such a dictionary there will probably be cases that cannot be handled automatically and you will be updating the dictionary often.

Comment: @Jim GarrisonThat's what I thought.. guess there is no solution after all

Comment: @JimGarrison Let's say I want to make this more accurate, how about accepting the names which has 2 to 4 words. And reject the names that has only 1 word or more than 4 words? I know it will still accept "Ngee Ann Polytechnic, etc"

Comment: Only you know what is acceptable.  If it was me I'd make a list of "non-name words" such as `Polytechnic`, `Institute`, `Technology`, `Design` etc and reject names containing one or more such words.  Just be careful to NOT include words that could be part of a person's name.

Comment: @JimGarrison Hi, thanks for the tip! Will update the question while trying it out :)

Comment: You're not being very kind to mr Anderson Primary School, who will not be able to enter his name in your application. Honestly, Singapore names can be anything, since people from all over the world live here. And there will be a lot of overlap between person names and company names.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I am rejecting "School" instead of Anderson. It should still be able to accept names like "John Anderson". I do not need this to be perfect as I am working on filtering between company and people name on a business card, and displaying to different EditText fields. If there is a slight mistake, it will still be editable manually.

Comment: There are plenty of people with the last name "School". Here's some info for your reference: http://names.mongabay.com/data/sa/SCHOOL.html. Note I live in Singapore and my last name is most likely not going to be in any positive list of valid last names that you would use. (I have to admit it would be cruel to give your son the middle name "Primary" if your family name is school. But probably not illegal.)

Comment: Here's a story about [mr Null and what bad name checks can to do somebody](http://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/). My advice: don't check name validity.  The variety is too big and there are no rules that you can follow.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt you are right, thanks a lot for your insight! :)

Answer (score 0):

Short of building a dictionary of disallowed words there is no solution to this problem. Even with such a dictionary there will probably be cases that cannot be handled automatically and you will be updating the dictionary often.

Only you know what is acceptable. If it was me I'd make a list of "non-name words" such as Polytechnic, Institute, Technology, Design etc and reject names containing one or more such words. Just be careful to NOT include words that could be part of a person's name.

However, (from @ErwinBolwidt): You're not being very kind to mr Anderson Primary School, who will not be able to enter his name in your application. Honestly, Singapore names can be anything, since people from all over the world live here. And there will be a lot of overlap between person names and company names.

There are plenty of people with the last name "School". Here's some info for your reference: [names.mongabay.com/data/sa/SCHOOL.html](http://names.mongabay.com/data/sa/SCHOOL.html). Note I live in Singapore and my last name is most likely not going to be in any positive list of valid last names that you would use. (I have to admit it would be cruel to give your son the middle name "Primary" if your family name is school. But probably not illegal.)

Here's a story about [mr Null and what bad name checks can to do somebody](http://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/). My advice: don't check name validity. The variety is too big and there are no rules that you can follow